# Send dynamic HTTP request in nodejs instead of hardcoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently, I am sending http requests using request module to an URL in nodejs program as

```
request('http://example.org/upload',function(error,response,data) {})
```

But I wish to send the http request to example.org dynamically to route to "upload" or "login" or "logout" based on the value stored in variable something like

```
var dynamic= "upload"
request('http://example.org/dynamic',function(error,response,data) {})
```

Above code is not working as expected as it is routing to dynamic in example.org. what should I do inorder to send the requests as desired?

Comment: `request('http://example.org/' + dynamic, function(error,response,data) {})` - string concatenation

Comment: thank you  Krzysztof Safjanowski, its working.